# how would I go about finding the distance between two points on earth

Tags: geometry, circles, spherical-geometry

I want to try and find the distance between two points on earth, as much by hand as possible. Could anyone give me ideas on how I would go about doing this, (explanations as deep as possible please!)

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27928).

Comment: Having the coordinates of the points, you can at least roughly determine the distance by hand by assuming a perfect sphere and based on the middle radius of the Earth, But why not use Google Earth or distance calculators on the internet ?

Comment: @Peter I am trying to use it in an essay which encourages as much by hand working as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that earth is a perfect sphere with radius $R$. Let $p_1, p_2$ be the points of interest, laying on the surface of the earth (i.e. $||p_i|| = R$). The points $p_1, p_2$, seen as vectors, create an angle $\theta$ between them. Thus, the distance (shortest path on the surface from $p_1$ to $p_2$) is given by $\theta R$. Draw a picture to convince yourself. The angle is given by
$$\theta = \arccos(\frac{p_1 \cdot p_2}{R^2})$$

Comment: @MatthewH. You are correct. I edited that out.